# Delete string and associated newline

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I'm trying to edit a file on a remote server via a terminal and to make a change in said file I have to (or have used so far) use the 'sed' command.

in the below file i want to delete the string `STUFF_456` and its new line character.

```
STUFF_123
STUFF_456
STUFF_789
```

However when I use this command in `sed` i'm left with a blank line.

```
$ sed -i 's/STUFF_456//' /file/path/here.txt
STUFF_123

STUFF_789
```

I need to get rid of the blank line and keep the other two entries.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the line with:

```
sed '/^STUFF_456$/d'
```

This `d`eletes every line being `STUFF_456`, `^` marks the beginning of the line and `$` marks the end.

With your example:

```
$ sed '/^STUFF_456$/d' /file/path/here.txt
STUFF_123
STUFF_789
```